# Based on the values in two columns merge values in other columns

Tags: python, merge, pandas

I have a tab delimited file with four columns. I need to combine 'col3' and 'col4' for each unique value pairs in 'col1' and 'col2'. An example and output is shown as under.

One way I am thinking of is to use nested loops: outer loop read the lines sequentially and the inner loop reads all lines from the begining and look for map. However this process seems to be computational intensive.

Is there an alternative way to do this.

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
a   c   1,2 physical
a   c   2,3 genetic
b   c   22  physical 
b   d   33,44   genetic
c   e   1,2 genetic
c   e   2   physical
c   f   33,44   physical
c   f   3   genetic
a   a   4   genetic
e   c   1,2 xxxxx


col1    col2    col3    col4
a   c   1,2,3   genetic,physical
a   a   4   genetic
b   c   22  physical 
b   d   33,44   genetic
c   e   1,2 genetic,physical,xxxxx
c   f   3,33,44 genetic,physical
```

It combines the values if 'col1' and 'col2' are switched as in the last line above with value 'xxxxx'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a dictionary of keys which are tuples that hold column1 and column2 data.  The values would be a list which holds column3 and column4 data...

```
from collections import defaultdict
with open('test.dat') as f:
    data = defaultdict( lambda:([],[]))
    header = f.readline()
    for line in f:
        col1,col2,col3,col4 = line.split()
        col3_data,col4_data = data[(col1,col2)]  #data[frozenset((col1,col2))] if order doesn't matter
        col3_data.append(col3)
        col4_data.append(col4)
```

Now sort and write the output (joining column3 and column4 lists with a `','`, making unique with `set` and `sorted` to order properly)

```
with open('outfile.dat','w') as f:
   f.write(header)
   #If you used a frozenset in the first part, you might want to do something like:
   #for k in sorted(map(sorted,data.keys())):
   for k in sorted(data.keys()):
       col1,col2 = k
       col3_data,col4_data = data[k]
       col3_data = ','.join(col3_data) #join the list
       col3_data = set(int(x) for x in col3_data.split(',')) #make unique integers
       col3_str = ','.join(map(str,sorted(col3_data)))       #sort, convert to strings and join with ','
       col4_data = ','.join(col4_data)  #join the list
       col4_data = sorted(set(col4_data.split(',')))  #make unique and sort
       f.write('{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\n'.format(col1,col2,col3_str,','.join(col4_data)))
```

Comment: Thanks @mgilson, but I am getting an error in  "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in <module>
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack". It is because of 7th line in the first part of the code.

Comment: @Curious -- I got that too before I tested the code.  See my revision.  (specifically, it should be `defaultdict(lambda:([],[]))` rather than `defaultdict(lambda:[],[])`.

Comment: thanks. Worked perfect as desired. Is there a way to disregard the ordering in col1 and col2. I edited this in the question.

Comment: @Curious -- You can use `col3_data,col4_data = data[frozenset((col1,col2))]` in the first part. . . That makes sorting the keys in the second part sort of worthless.

Comment: @Curious -- See the comments I've added (both parts).

Comment: with frozen set, the 7th line in second part "col3_data,col4_data = data[k]" is showing " unhashable type: list" error.

Answer (score 2):

@mgilson gave a good no-extra-parts required solution (+1).  I see that `pandas` is tagged too, so for completeness I'll give a `pandas` equivalent:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("merge.csv",delimiter=r"\s*")

key_cols = ["col1", "col2"]
df[key_cols] = df[key_cols].apply(sorted, axis=1)

def join_strings(seq, key):
    vals = [term for entry in seq for term in entry.split(',')]
    return ','.join(sorted(set(vals), key=key))

new_df = df.groupby(key_cols).agg({"col3": lambda x: join_strings(x, int),
                                   "col4": lambda x: join_strings(x, str)})
new_df.to_csv("postmerged.csv")
```

which produces

```
In [173]: !cat postmerged.csv
col1,col2,col3,col4
a,a,4,genetic
a,c,"1,2,3","genetic,physical"
b,c,22,physical
b,d,"33,44",genetic
c,e,"1,2","genetic,physical,xxxxx"
c,f,"3,33,44","genetic,physical"
```

All this does is (1) sort the first two columns so that `e c` becomes `c e`, (2) group the terms by `col` and `col 2`, and then aggregate (`agg`) `col3` and `col4` by comma-joining the sorted set of the flattened terms.

`groupby` is really handy for things like this.  There might be a built-in replacement for the `join_strings` function lurking somewhere too, but I'm not sure.